# how to log requested path in access log?

Tags: spring, jboss, jboss-eap-7

We are using Jboos Eap 7.1 in our organization with access log enabled with the following pattern:

```
<access-log pattern="%h %l %u %t %r %s %b %{Referer}i %{User-Agent}i %{COOKIE}i %{SET-COOKIE}o %S %I %T"/>
```

Each 5 minutes server log says:

[org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] (default task-49) Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]

But in access log we see:

```
    GET /general-error.html HTTP/1.1 404
```

Which is a fallback page for errors, so we don't know which url or spring controller is being requested, how can I see actual requested path like nginx does?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Request logging / RequestDumping handler using following commands.

1. Create a new Expression Filter with the RequestDumping Handler

`/subsystem=undertow/configuration=filter/expression-filter=requestDumperExpression:add(expression="dump-request")`

2. Enable the Expression Filter in the Undertow Web Server

`/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/filter-ref=requestDumperExpression:add`

Above commands will add the following configuration in domain.xml/standalone.xml in undertow subsystem

```
<server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                ...
                <filter-ref name="requestDumperExpression"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        ...
        <filters>
            ...
            <expression-filter name="requestDumperExpression" expression="dump-request"/>
        </filters>
```

The output will be logged in `server.log` file.

Refer following url for more detail : 
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2429371

Comment: thanks! it helped me to find out which controller was being invoked and from where, this should be the accepted answer but I can't

Comment: @JassielDíaz I think, it's because of your reputation